# Match exact string in dataframe column

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe, string-matching

How do I find an exact match of a string in a dataframe column?

Currently, I am searching col_8 for the string '1' and it is returning True for row #2, but I want it to be false because it is actually 12. Thanks in advance!

```
df['new'] = np.where(df['col_8'].str.contains('1'),1,0)
print(df)

    col_8  col_9  new
0    1,2,3  7     1
1    1,3,8  10    1
2    12     8     1
3    9      3     0
```

Comment: try split, ``df.col_8.apply(lambda  x : 1 if "1" in x.split(",") else 0)``

Answer (score 0):

This would work

```
df['new'] = np.where(df['col_8'].str.contains('1,'),1,0)
```